# Can I use Windows 8 Mail App as the medium to send email through using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I'm building an application for a college project on vehicular insurance, and I already have several components ready, including generating PDFs using iTextSharp.
I'm trying to add a module wherein I can automatically send the generated PDF to the "customer" via e-mail.
Using the methods in this tutorial - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268749.aspx I am able to use Outlook to send the mail.
My question is - Can I use the default Mail App in Windows 8.x to send mail instead of Outlook? I couldn't find a satisfactory answer in my preliminary search.

Thank you.

Comment: .NET has a built-in SMTP client. I don't see the need to use a stand-alone client like Outlook or Windows Mail. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this sample. It demonstarates sharing content between apps.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84